# Django separate out SQL logging

Tags: python, sql, django, logging

I know in Django that I can view all SQL statements as logs using `django.db.backends` as a logger in my `settings.py`. However, I don't know of a good way to know which SQL statement came from which Django script and function that I wrote. I've looked into `q.as_sql()` and `q.sql_with_params()`, where `q` is a queryset, and I've tried to log each queryset's SQL statements using these.

However, it seems like these functions are for older versions of Django that aren't supported anymore? I've also tried to give the `django.db.backends` logger a handler whose format includes filename and function, but the filename is always `utils.py`, which I assume is the Django script that either does the logging or does the execution of the SQL. What I'm trying to do is modify the SQL logs that `django.db.backends` produces so that, for example, if I do this kind of query:

`val, created = Value.objects.get_or_create(val_type=int)`

in a function `insertIntoDatabase()` in a file named `databaseinserter.py`, the logs will not only show the raw SQL involved in that query but also show me that the SQL statement came from the function `insertIntoDatabase()` from the file `databaseinserter.py`. How can I achieve this? It would be great to have the SQL logs also log the line number of what Django code caused what SQL statement.